# vfb- what is the purpose of the virtual framebuffer?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, framebuffer, xvfb

I have seen this config flag `CONFIG_FB_VIRTUAL=y`

- What does it do?
- How does it work?
- What is the relation between `vfb` and `xvfb`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this page](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/FB_VIRTUAL.html), it's for testing.  It's a framebuffer that's in main memory instead of graphics memory, so you basically can't see it, but if your app environment needs a framebuffer for whatever reason and your hardware doesn't have graphics (not uncommon in embedded apps) then it can be useful.

xvfb is a very different beast.  It creates its own virtual framebuffer in userspace for use as an X display.  It can be used with programs that need an X connection (e.g. older versions of [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)) but for some reason the system doesn't have an existing X display.  It doesn't need any kind of support from the kernel to do this - it uses a framebuffer, but really a framebuffer is just a fancy term for a chunk of memory used for a graphical screen.